# Trying to install postgresql:i386 on 12.04 amd64

Tags: installation, apt, 64-bit, postgresql

Due to some legacy 32 bit libraries being used in postgresql functions I need to get a 32 bit install of Postgresql on a 64 bit native system.  But it seems like there is a problem with the multiarch not seeing all.debs as satisfying dependencies.

`uname -a`:

```
3.8.0-29-generic #42-precise-Ubuntu SMP x86_64
```

`dpkg --print-architecture`:

```
amd64
```

`dpkg --print-foreign-architecture`:

```
i386
```

`apt-get install postgresql-9.1`:

returns

```
postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.1 but it is nto going to be installed
postgresql-9.1:i386 : Depends: postgresql-common:i386 but it is not installable
                      Depends: ssl-cert:i386 but it is not installable
                      Depends: locales:i386 but it is not installable
```

etc ..

But I have installed `ssl-cert_1.0.28ubuntu0.1_all.deb` and `locales_..._all.deb`
and`postgresql-common` is an `all.deb`

Does anyone have experience installing 32 bit packages on 64 bit systems that depend on packages that are all.debs.

Or has anyone installed 32 bit `postgres` on 64 bit?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To install 32-bit packages on 64-bit you need to run the following: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs -y`. In Ubuntu 13.10, there is no longer a need to do this.

Comment: ia32-libs and ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 are installed.  I have compiled and installed and run other 32 bit packages but postgresql is proving difficult

Comment: Sounds like a packaging bug in 12.04 for some reason. I don't have any 12.04 machines so I can't test for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help installing the i386 postgresql, (try the lower level package routines) but you will still have to add 3 more libraries not included in the ia32 libs:

```
$ ldd /mnt/sda1/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/* | fgrep found |sort -u
    libedit.so.2 => not found
    libpam.so.0 => not found
    libpq.so.5 => not found
```

(From a 12.04 64 bit system with ia32libs and multiarch, looking at a mounted 32bit 12.04 root partition).